# Selecting all the items in dropdown using powerapps

Tags: listbox, powerapps, listboxitem, powerapps-formula

I am trying to select all the items in dropdown using Powerapps. Below are the codes I was trying :

Concat(ListBox2_1.SelectedItems, Value & ",")

First(ListBox2_1.SelectedItems).Value

Concat(ListBox2_1.SelectedItems, Value & ",")

Please advise

Comment: Are you trying to select all items in a dropdown or a listbox (based on the name)? Are you trying to *select* the items, or to *display* the selected items? For the expressions that you are using what error (or result) do you get?

Comment: I have some values that I need to hard code in items sections

Comment: So you want to pre-select the items... And to the other questions: are you using a dropdown (based on the title of the question), a listbox (based on the examples), or some other control?

Comment: And a question that we'll probably need to know as well: what is the source of the items in the control (the value of its `Items` property)?

Comment: I am using the Listbox control with these values ["Admin","Finance","HR","IT","ITES","Management"]. I want all these values selected when form is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to select multiple default values in the listbox (https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Ideas/ListBox-support-for-multiple-default-values/idi-p/280491). A control that supports multiple defaults that you can use would be the combo box. In this case, you would use the same expression for the Items property:

```
["Admin","Finance","HR","IT","ITES","Management"]
```

and the DefaultSelectedItems property:

```
["Admin","Finance","HR","IT","ITES","Management"]
```